# I can't access a pop-up with Cypress

Tags: cypress

i'm trying to run a simple Cypress scenario.
Access this url : https://www.harmonie-mutuelle.fr/ and close the pop-up that appears.
But the pop-up seems to have a weird behavior. It doesn't appear in the navigator on the right when i run my test but it appears in the middle of the screen as if it was a Cypress pop-up (i don't know if i'm clear)
[image]

Here is a my code :

```js
cy.viewport(1920, 1080);

cy.visit('https://www.harmonie-mutuelle.fr/');

cy.get('#popin_tc_privacy_container_button > button').eq(2).click();
```

Any ideas as to how i can close that pop-up ?

Comment: I visited the site, never having visited before, and did not see the pop up after scrolling around.

Answer (score 0):

ok managed to find a solution. Here's a way to do it using wrap if anyone needs this :

```
cy.visit('https://www.harmonie-mutuelle.fr/').then(() => {

        cy.wrap(window.top.document.querySelector('#popin_tc_privacy_button_3')).click();

    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really wrong with your approach, but to explain what's happening -

Cypress commands like `cy.get()` starts searching at the `<body>` element. You can modify it using the `.within()` command.

Most commonly used to set the root element to a descendant element of `<body>` but should also work to move it to the parent `<html>` element, which is what your test requires.

```js
cy.visit('https://www.harmonie-mutuelle.fr/');

cy.document()
  .find('html')
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('#popin_tc_privacy_container_button > button').eq(2).click()
  })
```